# How to implicitly differentiate $x \sin x = y(1 + \cos y)$?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

If $x \sin x = y(1 + \cos y)$, find $y'$ at $(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{3})$. Please show each step.

Comment: You don't "imply".  You apply the method. ;)

Comment: To maximize your chance of receiving a good answer, you should explain what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the following:

- Product rule: $\dfrac{d}{dx}[f(x)g(x)] = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$
- Chain rule: $\dfrac{d}{dx}[f(g(x))] = f'(g(x))g'(x)$
- $\dfrac{d}{dx}[\cos(x)] = -\sin(x)$
- $\dfrac{d}{dx}[\sin(x)] = \cos(x)$

When performing implicit differentiation, you decide which variable to differentiate.  For instance, if we have an equation with variables $x$ and $y$, and we want to differentiate it with respect to $x$, then the derivative of $y$ is $y'$, whereas the $x$ terms are differentiated by the usual derivative rules.

For your problem, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
x\sin(x) &= y(1 + \cos(y))\\
x\sin(x) &= y + y\cos(y)
\end{aligned}$$

Then,

$$\begin{aligned}
x\cos(x) + \sin(x) = y' + y'\cos(y) - y\sin(y) \cdot y'
\end{aligned}$$

which is simplified as

$$y' = \dfrac{x\cos(x) + \sin(x)}{1 + \cos(y) - y\sin(y)}$$

Here is how this is derived:

1. The derivative of $x\cos(x)$ is found by product rule.
2. The derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ is $y'$.
3. The derivative of $\cos(y)$ with respect to $x$ is $\sin(y)\cdot y'$. Use chain rule for this part.
4. To differentiate $y\cos(y)$ with respect to $x$, use product rule.

The rest is left for you to determine $y'$ for $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{3} \right)$.  Simply substitute $x$ with $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $y$ with $\frac{\pi}{3}$.  Finally, solve for $y'$.

Comment: thank you so much, I understand it so much better now

Answer (score 0):

First, recall that $(\sin x)' = \cos x$, $(\cos x)' = -\sin x$, and $(\alpha)' = 0$ for any real number $\alpha$. Also, by the chain rule, the derivative of $f(y)$ with respect to $x$ is $f'(y)y'$.

If we differentiate both sides of $x \sin x = y(1 + \cos y)$ with respect to $x$, we get
$$x \cos x + \sin x = -yy' \sin y + (1 + \cos y)y'.$$
Note that we used both the product rule and the chain rule. Hence
$$x \cos x + \sin x = [(1 + \cos y) - y \sin y]y',$$
that is,
$$y' = \frac{x \cos x + \sin x}{1 + \cos y - y \sin y}.$$
Now substitute $x = \pi/2$ and $y = \pi/3$.

Comment: Thank I substituted and got 6/9−π√3 @glebovg